# Python: How to convert horizontal list of data points into vertical dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, average

I have a variable that is a horizontal list of data points (x, y). How do I convert this:

```
[(6493.16, 3.12), (5575.26, 2.76), (5571.83, 14.73), (7202.88, 3.08), (7569.92, 4.01), (7289.38, 10.24)]
```

to this:

```
6493.16, 3.12
5575.26, 2.76
5571.83, 14.73
7202.88, 3.08
7569.92, 4.01
7289.38, 10.24
```

such that i can store all the y values in a separate variable and then take an average of all the y values?

Comment: Do you mean a pandas dataframe?

Comment: You can get all the y values with a list comprehension: `y_vals = [x[1] for x in datapoints]`

Comment: Yes, any type of variable that will let me isolate the y values and then compute the average of the y values.

Comment: You can do that with the original list, you don't need another type of variable.

Comment: what is x in your comment? would x be the variable where all these points are stored?

Comment: `x` is each element of `datapoints`, which is the list you showed.

Comment: If you don't understand it, you need to read a tutorial on list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign it to variable then use `pandas.DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

x = [(6493.16, 3.12), (5575.26, 2.76), (5571.83, 14.73), (7202.88, 3.08), (7569.92, 4.01), (7289.38, 10.24)]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list is just a matrix 6x2.

Use **numpy** to get the second column from your matrix.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([(6493.16, 3.12), (5575.26, 2.76), (5571.83, 14.73), (7202.88, 3.08), (7569.92, 4.01), (7289.38, 10.24)])

#to get n-th column from matrix A, where n=0,1,2,.. use: A[:, n]
#in your case:
y = A[:, 1]

#and you can applay mean on this column
avg = np.mean(y)
```